# How can I refactor/ simplify the following php function?

Tags: php, optimization, refactoring

I have a function that will return how many products there are on an invoice and it seems pretty straightforward to me but maybe it can use some refactoring?

```
    public function getTotalProductsNumber(): int
{
    $dataset = 'supplier_invoice_products inner join supplier_invoices as si using (supplier_invoice_id)';
    $dbmSupplier = new Dbm_Supplier($dataset);

    $whereAndOpt = $this->getConditionsAndOptions();
    $where = $whereAndOpt['where'];
    $opt = $whereAndOpt['opt'];
    $select = 'sum(product_quantity) as sumTotal';
    $invoiceTotalProductsNumber =  $dbmSupplier->findFirstSimple($where, $select, $opt);
    $invoiceTotalProductsNumber['sumTotal'] = (int)$invoiceTotalProductsNumber['sumTotal'];
    return $invoiceTotalProductsNumber['sumTotal'];
}
```

How can I extract this into at least two functions?

Comment: This question rather belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Code-wise, at least last two lines look extremely useless. I would just [get rid of useless assignments](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/1c8161c483ae25970e93c1c4caec1cd5/) and call it a day. But what should be **really** refactored here is the structure of both classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of thing, ideally you'd use an ORM. As I'm not sure which you're using, if at all, I'd probably refactor it to something more in this direction so it feels closer to how an ORM would work:

```
public function getTotalProductsNumber(): int
{
    $dataset = 'supplier_invoice_products inner join supplier_invoices as si using (supplier_invoice_id)';
    $extras = $this->getConditionsAndOptions();
    $queryBuilder = [
        'dbm' => new Dbm_Supplier($dataset),
        'where' =>  $extras['where'],
        'opt' => $extras['opt']
    ];
    return $this->sumOfProductQuantities($queryBuilder);
}

private function sumOfProductQuantities(array $queryBuilder): int
{
    $select = 'sum(product_quantity) as sumTotal';
    $row = $this->queryBuilderFirstRow($queryBuilder, $select);
    return (int)$row['sumTotal'];
}

private function queryBuilderFirstRow(array $qb, string $select): array
{
    return $qb['dbm']->findFirstSimple($qb['where'], $select, $qb['opt']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally think this is pretty straightforward and nicely clean, but the only optimization I can suggest is to extract `getConditionsAndOptions` part as it seems to be used in some other several parts of your code. Look at this please:

```
public function getTotalProductsNumber(): int
{
    $dataset = 'supplier_invoice_products inner join supplier_invoices as si using (supplier_invoice_id)';
    $dbmSupplier = new Dbm_Supplier($dataset);

    list($where, $opt) = $this->getWhereAndOpt();

    $select = 'sum(product_quantity) as sumTotal';
    $invoiceTotalProductsNumber = $dbmSupplier->findFirstSimple($where, $select, $opt);
    $invoiceTotalProductsNumber['sumTotal'] = (int)$invoiceTotalProductsNumber['sumTotal'];
    return $invoiceTotalProductsNumber['sumTotal'];
}

private function getWhereAndOpt(): array
{
    $whereAndOpt = $this->getConditionsAndOptions();
    return [
        $whereAndOpt['where'],
        $whereAndOpt['opt'],
    ];
}
```

Another point maybe name conventions. I can see you have used `snail_case` naming for Dbm_Supplier. It's better to be either `dbm_supplier` or `DbmSupplier`.

Comment: As of PHP 7.1.0 you can specify keys in list() or its new shorthand syntax []. This enables "destructuring" of arrays with non-integer or non-sequential keys. Thus `['where' => $where, 'opt' => $opt] = $this->getConditionsAndOptions();`

Comment: But list can provide simple variables from a numeric indexed array and it's much simpler. Your code still uses an array and I think it's not a simplification.